# Calculations of files

Tags: c, matlab

```
Day              price1          price2

2/2/2000         10                15

3/2/2000         12                18

4/2/2000         14                19
```

For every value (price 1 and price 2) I want to calculate different = now-past (line2-line1) for every column.

To make this is it right to use a table, any example?

What I have

```
file = xlsread('example.xls');

y = length(price);

for i=1:y;
  difprice1 = line(i+1)-line(i)
  difprice2 = line(i+1)-line(i)

end
```

Comment: To obtain matrix `A` from my answer in your case, you simply index `file`. To exclude the first column for this operation, `A = file(:, 2:end);` may be appropriate, but you can also work with `A = file;`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for i = 1:length(price1)-1
    Diff(i,1) = price1(i+1)-price1(i);
    Diff(i,2) = price2(i+1)-price2(i);
end

or more efficiently:

Diff(:,1) = price1(2:end)-price1(1:end-1);
Diff(:,2) = price2(2:end)-price2(1:end-1);
....
Diff(:,N) = priceN(2:end)-priceN(1:end-1);
```

of course the price vectors all have to be of same length.

Comment: taking the length from a .xls file of column how can I make it?

Comment: next time you should finish your question before posting it ;), look at the other answer for what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If your prices are stored in an `m`x`n` matrix A with `m` consecutive days and `n` different products/prices, you can get the day to day change simply by `A(2:end, :) - A(1:end-1, :)`.

This calculation takes the matrix of all "next day" prices and subtracts the matrix of all "today" prices element by element, resulting in all price changes along the entire time window.

```
A = xlsread('example.xls');
dA = A(2:end, :) - A(1:end-1, :)
```

Now `dA(:, 2:end)` contains all the numbers you were asking for.