# Plotting data from files

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculations of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265718/calculations-of-files)

```
Day              price1          price2

2/2/2000         10                15

3/2/2000         12                18

4/2/2000         14                19
```

How could I plot x=day and y=price1?

```
file = xlsread('example.xls');

x = file(:,1);

y = file(:,2);


plot(x,y);
```

It doesn't give the days in x line it gives numbers 0, 1, 2 insted of 2/2/2000

Comment: Do you already have code that's broken, or are you trying to get someone to just write the code for you?

Comment: Is this `C` or `MATLAB`? Why are both tagged?

Comment: Huh? How is this a duplicate of the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265718/calculations-of-files)? This question concerns getting plots to display dates instead of numbers. The linked question concerns finding the difference between two sequential price observations - I know because I checked before answering. What am I missing?!?

Comment: ps If anyone with 3000 rep comes past here, please have a look at the linked question, and if you agree with me, please vote to reopen. Otherwise, please add a comment indicating how this question duplicates, cause it sure ain't obvious to me!

Comment: I agree with @ColinTBowers this should be opened again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date strings to label your `xtick` marks in the plot. First we need to convert the date number to a date sting, using `datestr`.

```
[file, text] = xlsread('example.xls');
x = file(:, 1);
y = file(:, 2);
x0 = datenum(2000, 2, 2);
cal = cellstr(datestr(x + x0));
```

Then we can plot and label the tickmarks.

```
plot(x, y);
set(gca(), 'xtick', 1 : length(y), 'xticklabel', cal);;
```

Comment: FYI I've suggested using `datetick` to solve the problem of getting dates on the x-axis. Have a look into it - once I discovered this marvelous function I never looked back :-) ps I agree that it is confusing that OP's current numbers start at 0. I think that is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

The neatest method for getting the x-axis to display dates is via the `datetick` function. I used to do it manually, as the other answers to this question suggest doing, until I discovered this wonderful function.

Cut and paste the following example into a Matlab script and run it line-by-line:

```
y = randn(4, 1); %# Simulate random observations
Dates = {'1/1/2000', '2/1/2000', '3/1/2000', '4/1/2000'}; %# Build a vector of date strings
DatesNum = datenum(Dates, 'dd/mm/yyyy'); %# Convert date strings to date numbers
plot(DatesNum, y); %# Plot the data
datetick('x', 'dd/mm/yyyy'); %# Convert date numbers on plot to string format
```

The last line essentially says "on the x axis of the current plot, display the numbers in date-time format, using the format string dd/mm/yyyy".

Once you are familiar with how this example works, you should be able to adapt this example to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an Excel COM server available (likely the case if you are running on unix/linux), the dates will appear as Excel serial date numbers (an integer). These are different from MATLAB date serial numbers. They can be converted using x2mdate():

```
file = xlsread('example.xls')
file(:,1) = x2mdate(file(:,1))
set(gca,'Xtick',file(:,1),'XTickLabel',datestr(file(:,1)))
```

Here I am assuming that the dates in your date column are formatted as dates by Excel/LibreOffice and not as strings.

Comment: Are you sure his numbers are serial date numbers? They wouldn't start with 0 for the first row, would they? In my answer I shift the date within `datenum`'s system, but that's not a great way to do it. I don't understand why he's seeing those numbers start at 0, do you?

Comment: I assumed serial date numbers because I thought that OP was only indicating that they were positive integers. If they really do start at 0, I agree, it's very strange.